# Mockito : Wanted but not invoked

Tags: java, amazon-s3, mockito, testng

I have a piece of code I am trying to test which does some transformation and uploads file to S3 inside a wrapper method.

I set up my S3 mock object and included

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
when(s3client.putObject(any(PutObjectRequest.class)))
             .thenReturn(putObjectResult);
```

in my `BeforeMethod`

In my actual test I do:

1. Construct an object of the class the wrapper method belongs to and pass the mock object.
2. Call the wrapper method using this object.
3. And then, I included this:

`verify(s3client).putObject(putObjectRequestArgumentCaptor.capture());`

But this always returns no interactions. I'm new to mockito, so I would appreciate any help on how I can set up unit test for this scenario.

Comment: Are you injecting the mock somewhere?

Comment: I'm passing the mock object to the constructor.

Comment: I think you need to try to run the test in debug mode within your IDE. Step through the function that is being tested and ensure that it interacts with the mock that you set in the constructor.

Comment: I actually traced through and found out the mock object was getting picked up. The problem was that the code was not reaching the place where the mock object should be used which is why my tst was failing. Thank you!